# Live and trigger in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function:

```
$('#def_video_settings .add_rem:contains(-)').live('click', function(){
        // do something
    });
```

I want execute code "//do something" at another place. Something like this

```
$('#def_video_settings .add_rem:contains(-)').trigger('click');
```

But it does not work.

It is possible? :)

Comment: not sure what you are asking? setting a live() (depreciated) on a button or some sort? Have you tried doing a simple `console.log()` output of your `$('#def_video_settings .add_rem:contains(-)')` if you are even grabbing what you need?

Comment: fyi, `live` has been deprecated. its replacement is `on`.

Comment: If you want to use the same // do something code elsewhere, you can always just assign the function to a variable or declare a named function and reference the name or variable name where you want it used. The rest of your question isn't clear, however, so maybe more explanation.

Comment: 1) `live` is deprecated use `on` instead
2) You only need to use `on` if you are adding content dynamically.

Comment: Your code should work... you should check to see if `$('#def_video_settings .add_rem:contains(-)')` actually returns any elements...

Comment: wirey, yes, my code does not work, because $('#def_video_settings .add_rem:contains(-)') not returns any element. My fault, I'm bad... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tjUk5/

HTML

```
<div id="def_video_settings">
    <a class="add_rem">123-abc</a>
</div>​
```

Script

```
$('#def_video_settings .add_rem:contains(-)').on('click', function(){
    alert('do something');
});

$('#def_video_settings .add_rem:contains(-)').trigger('click');
​
```

This is working as it should.

If you are adding content dynamically, this might be different.

Comment: Shmiddty, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181800/live-and-trigger-in-jquery#comment16324958_12181800 :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#def_video_settings .add_rem:contains(-)').click();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this counts as an expected answer, but my first guess is

`$('#def_video_settings .add_rem:contains(-)').live('click', fnDoSomething);`

As in keep it as a proper function rather than an anonymous one, which you can call from somewhere else?

`function fnDoSomething(){
    // Do Something
}`

Of Course, i could be wrong.